# Delphi with MySQL 64-bit Firedac

Tags: mysql, delphi

Hello I have been using MySQL, 64 bit with Firedac in my development environment, and am trying to move the app to a new machine. I have installed MySQL 8 on the new machine and works fine.

I have made a simple app to connect in delphi XE8. I built a 64 bit application. I include a mysql dll in the directory of the executable. It seems to need to be

libmysql.dll from 6/10.2019 @ 09:51 3,984 KB. If I remove this file from the exe directory on the development machine, I get error:

**[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libmysql.dll or libmysqld.dll]. The specified module could not be found. Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories and has x64 bitness.**

I can run the program outside of the IDE only with the libmysql.dll included in the exe directory.

If I copy the folder which contains the application to a new machine, whether the libmysql.dll is included in the directory or not, I get the same error, as above.

Can anyone with experience in MySQL 64 version 8 and Firedac please help me to get this working? It should really be a simple thing, and it needs to work on a new machine without delphi installed.

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Use [Depency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which dependencies you are missing on the target host

Answer (score 1):

You will get the same error message if your `libmysql.dll` is actually missing and if a library that `libmysql.dll` requires is missing. In both cases,  the library cannot be loaded.

While you should of course first make sure that the library can be found (e.g. by placing it into the same directory as your executable), the usual reason for this problem is that the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145) is missing. It is a [prerequirement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/windows-installation.html) for `libmysql.dll` and the MySQL server itself (and a lot of other software), and you need to install this package on the target system.

Optionally, for SSL support, you additionally need [OpenSSL libraries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries). They do not necessarily need to be installed, you can just copy the 2 dlls e.g. to the same directory as the `libmysql.dll`.

Comment: Thank you, SolarFlare. I am wondering if it's my version of Delphi XE8 / FireDac trying to access the correct libmysql.dll. I installed MYSQL 8, so I wonder if the dll is not compatible... However, if I installed MySQL correctly, should I also have installed visual C++ redistributable?

Comment: The MySQL server will also requires the runtime libraries (but you do not necessarily have to install MySQL server on your new system if you e.g. want to access a remote server). If you have the libmysql.dll in the same directory as your application.exe, it should use and find it, if not, make sure to test that first (as it's obviously possible that your dll is actually not found). But the usual suspect for your error is the missing vc++ runtime package (and it will give you the same error as if the dll isn't there at all), and there is no harm in installing it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have the libmysql.dll in the same path in both machines. If you have it where your executable resides, then the path of the executable in both machines should be exactly the same. Since typically when you build the path of the executable is ..\project_name\debug or release\Win32 or Win64, the easiest solution is to have a folder "C:\MySQLlib" in both machines and copy there the dll. From the IDE you then assign in the vendorlib property "C:\MySQLlib\libmysql.dll" and everything runs smooth in both machines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).